# Textures only show in first line in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am experimenting with Java, I have a save file that the game reads that is made up like the following;[image]

The 0's are a grass texture(this works) but when I change the 0's to 1's to change the grass to a stone it does not work past the first like I can change them to a 1 and it works fine but not the rest. I have sat and tried to find the problem for a while, but can't. I will update with more information.

The code that handles the block types is this;

```
public class Value {
    public static int groundGrass = 0;
    public static int groundRoad = 1;

    public static int airAir = -1;
}
```

This handles the file saves;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Save {
    public void loadSave(File loadPath){
        try{
            Scanner loadScanner = new Scanner(loadPath);

            while(loadScanner.hasNext()){
                for(int y=0;y<Screen.room.block.length;y++){
                    for(int x=0;x<Screen.room.block[0].length;x++){
                        Screen.room.block[y][x].groundID = loadScanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                for(int y=0;y<Screen.room.block.length;y++){
                    for(int x=0;x<Screen.room.block[0].length;x++){
                        Screen.room.block[y][x].airID = loadScanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }
            }

            loadScanner.close();
        } catch(Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

This handles the different block types;

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Block extends Rectangle{
    public int groundID;
    public int airID;

    public Block(int x, int y, int width, int height, int groundID, int airID){
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        this.groundID = groundID;
        this.airID = airID;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(Screen.tileset_ground[groundID], x, y, width, height, null);

        if(airID !=Value.airAir){
            g.drawImage(Screen.tileset_ground[airID], x, y, width, height, null);
        }
    }
}
```

That should be the important parts.

I added in e.printStackTrace(); (In the correct place?)

And got this in the console;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.humans.vs.technology.Save.loadSave(Save.java:14)
    at com.humans.vs.technology.Screen.define(Screen.java:39)
    at com.humans.vs.technology.Screen.paintComponent(Screen.java:47)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Full code Download if it helps - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3531994/HvsT.zip

Comment: You forgot to give us your code.

Comment: I don't think too many people will be willing to trawl through an entire project. You should post the important part of your code only.

Comment: @jli Thanks, I have updated this in the post.

Comment: @hammy78 please add `e.printStackTrace` to the `catch` in `loadSave` and show us the trace. There is a chance an exception is thrown and the code quits, causing the rest of the array to remain with its default values (`0`) -- which is then interpreted as grass.

Comment: @veer I probably put it in the wrong place, but like this;

  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `e.printStackTrace` to the exception handler in `loadSave`, it produced the following output:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.humans.vs.technology.Save.loadSave(Save.java:14)
>           at com.humans.vs.technology.Screen.define(Screen.java:39)
>           at com.humans.vs.technology.Screen.paintComponent(Screen.java:47)
>           ...
> ```

The line in question is:

```
Screen.room.block[y][x].groundID = loadScanner.nextInt();
```

Since we know `loadScanner` didn't hasn't been `null` and wasn't `null` prior (since it was clearly initialized just a few lines above, and the **first 8 ground tiles load correctly**), we figure the exception is probably produced from `Scene.room.block[y][x].groundID`.

We can rule out `Screen.room` and `Screen.room.block` from being the `null` references using the same logic as we used to eliminate `loadScanner` as a candidate. It appears some `block[y][x]` are `null`. Searching for the initialization of `Room.block`, we find `Room.define`, seen below.

```
public void define(){
    block = new Block[worldHeight][worldWidth];

    for(int y=0;y<block.length;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<block.length;x++){
            block[y][x] = new Block((Screen.myWidth/2) - ((worldWidth * blockSize)/2) + (x * blockSize), y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize, Value.groundGrass, Value.airAir);
        }
    }
}
```

As I hope you notice, your loops cover `x`, `y` in the interval *[0, `block.length`]*; `block.length` corresponds to `worldHeight`, and the problem becomes clear: **this loop only initializes the first 8x8 of block**. Once we attempt to read into `Screen.room.block[y][x].groundID` for, say, the block @ 0, 8, we find it is the default value, `null`. A `NullPointerException` is thrown which is caught by your exception handler and the rest of the save file is left unread. The 8x8 part of `blocks` which **is** initialized has it's `groundID` left as the default value, `0`, which corresponds to grass:

> ```
>   public static int groundGrass = 0;
> ```

At first, I suspected this would also cause a unfinished render of only the first 8 blocks in the first row of the room, too, since `Room.draw` calls `block[y][x].draw(g)` in a loop... however, your loop conditions are similarly broken here, too.

---

Now, the solution is simple. Correct the loop conditions in `Room.define` and `Room.draw`, e.g.

```
    for(int y=0;y<worldHeight;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<worldWidth;x++){
            block[y][x] = new Block((Screen.myWidth/2) - ((worldWidth * blockSize)/2) + (x * blockSize), y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize, Value.groundGrass, Value.airAir);
        }
    }
```

for `Room.define`, as well as the following for `Room.draw`.

```
    for(int y=0;y<worldHeight;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<worldWidth;x++){
            block[y][x].draw(g);
        }
    }
```

Your code now produces the following:
http://puu.sh/YvAJ
You're welcome :-)